# Error when inserting a datetime field into Oracle db using C#.

Tags: c#, oracle

I am attempting to import an XML file using a C# application. My issue is when I attempt to import a datetime field that belongs to the primary key I receive an error, "A non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected". This only occurs when executing from systems that have a custom date time format set up. I run into the problem using "hh mm dd MMM yy" as the date time format on my local machine. Is it possible to change the format of the datetime object to not match the system format?

Comment: How about showing some sample data and code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can parse the DateTime out of the XML into a DateTime object, then you can [format it however you please](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx).

If you don't want to do that, it's worth looking into how Oracle accepts DateTimes via their own [Q&A](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/insert_date.php) that shows a [TO_DATE](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php)() function that even accepts formatting for the DateTime string.

Cheers.

Note: As OldProgrammer said, sample code would've been tremendously helpful. Due to my low reputation, I was unable to add a comment so I decided to do a little research to answer what I can.